# Redshift - Limit vs Rank for paging

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm writing some complex queries that run against Redshift but am finding that paging is causing the queries to run slowly. I am currently paging in the UI by incrementing offset with limits when executing the queries, ie:

- offset 20 limit 20
- offset 40 limit 20

Is this because the change in the offset, the only variable that changes in the large query, causes the query to recompile?

If I use 'rank() over (order by col1) ranking' and use a where clause it doesn't appear to recompile, ie:

- where ranking between 21 and 40
- where ranking between 41 and 60

Basically, is ranking the only option I have if I want to avoid the extra compile?

Comment: Since redshift is based on pg-8.x; there are no window functions, so rank() is not an option for you. (Window functions wer introduced in postgres-8.4)

Comment: @wildplasser there are window functions in Redshift: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Window_functions.html

Comment: Is your query with offset 40, as fast as with offset 0 or slower? I doubt that compilation has anything to do with it.

Comment: I use rank() etc all the time in Redshift.

Comment: @quarterdome; it's the same, ie roughly three seconds on first execution for either level of offset, re-running then takes around 100ms, or a new offset level takes 2 seconds again. If I use rank and where then the first is still two seconds but as I'm now only changing the where clause, all subsequent requests are circa 100ms. I guess rank() is my only option. The queries are completely dynamic though so building the rank is a little more cumbersome than simply adding offset and limit to page.

Comment: Could you past the actual query with rank(), as well as what is your sortkey and distkey on Redshift table?